# Audio file in jar made by Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, audio, jar, ide

I have an swing app. Where I use wav file to make alarm. I put Alarm.wav in folder where I have *.class is bin folder. And it works. I use this code to get wav file and play it.

```
    InputStream in;
    try {

        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Alarm.wav");
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem
                .getAudioInputStream(is);       
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audioInputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when I made in Eclipse runnable jar there is no sound in my app.

Comment: Did check whether the wave file gets exported into the JAR file?

Comment: If it is, check whether prepending the file name with / or the correct path works, if not you can mark the file's containing folder as a source folder

Answer (score 0):

I have similiar problem.
Try use this code:

```
InputStream in;
    try {

        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("Alarm.wav"));       
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audioInputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thats is not correct cause AudioPlayer.player.start(audioInputStream) need Stream not URL.

Comment: I edit my answer. It should be work, `AudioInputStream` si a stream.